# Why did Excel's referenced cells stop being colored?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, gui, cross-reference, usability

In the last week, Excel for Mac v16.13 (180513) stopped coloring the cells referenced in a formula when editing (see by pressing `F2` when in a cell).

How can I get Excel to show these again?  Is it a bug in the latest patch or did these get turned off in a setting somewhere or did my install get corrupted somehow?

Comment: May be while edit something went wrong, so that Excel doesn't works. Better you upload the Screen Shot & the Formula you have applied, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: @RajeshS The problem exists with all formulas in all spreadsheets I open.